Showing $\int_{-1}^{1}\ln \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right) \left( x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) \, dx=\frac{\pi^2 + 4}{2}$
While exploring possible applications for exponential substitution, I stumbled upon the following integral identity:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\ln \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right) \left( x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) \, dx = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}} \ln \left( x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) \, dx = \frac{\pi^2 + 4}{2}$$
Assume complex-valued logarithms.

To prove it, we'll use exponential substitution $(es)$.
\begin{aligned}I_1=\int \ln \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right) \left( x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) \, dx &\overset{es}{=} i\int \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{i\alpha}}{1-e^{i\alpha}}\right) \left(1-e^{-2i\alpha}\right) \, d\alpha\\&=i\left(\underbrace{\int \ln (1+e^{i\alpha}) \left(1 - e^{-2i\alpha}\right) \, d\alpha}_{J} - \underbrace{\int \ln (1-e^{i\alpha}) \left(1 - e^{-2i\alpha}\right) \, d\alpha}_{K} \right) \end{aligned}
Let's solve $J$.
$$\begin{aligned}\int \ln (1+e^{i\alpha}) \left(1 - e^{-2i\alpha}\right) \, d\alpha&\overset{u=e^{i\alpha}}{=}-i \int \ln(1 + u) \left(\frac{u^2 - 1}{u^3}\right) du\\&= -i \left( \underbrace{\int \frac{\ln(1 + u)}{u} \, du}_{M} - \underbrace{\int \frac{\ln(1 + u)}{u^3} \, du}_{N} \right)\end{aligned}$$
Let's solve $M$. By making $v=-u$, we have
\begin{aligned}\int \frac{\ln(1 + u)}{u} \, du &=-\int -\frac{\ln(1-v)}{v} \, dv \\&= -\operatorname{Li}_2(v) + C_1 \\&= -\operatorname{Li}_2(-u) + C_1\\&=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{i\alpha})+C_1\end{aligned}
Now let's solve $N$ by parts and partial fraction decomposition.
$$\begin{aligned} \int \frac{\ln(1 + u)}{u^3} \, du&=-\frac{\ln(u + 1)}{2u^2} + \frac12\int \frac{1}{u^2 (u + 1)} \, du\\&= -\frac{\ln(u + 1)}{2u^2}+\frac12\left(\int \frac{1}{u + 1} \, du - \int \frac{1}{u} \, du + \int \frac{1}{u^2} \, du \right)\\&=-\frac{\ln(u + 1)}{2u^2}+\frac{\ln (u+1)}{2}-\frac{\ln (u)}{2}-\frac{1}{2u}+C_2\\&=-\frac{\ln(e^{i\alpha} + 1)}{2e^{2i\alpha}} + \frac{\ln(e^{i\alpha} + 1)}{2} - \frac{i\alpha}{2} - \frac{1}{2e^{i\alpha}} + C_2 \end{aligned}$$
Combining $M$ and $N$ and then simplifying, we have
$$J=\frac{ie^{-2i\alpha} \left( e^{2i\alpha} - 1 \right) \ln\left( e^{i\alpha} + 1 \right) - i e^{-i\alpha} + \alpha}{2} + i \, \text{Li}_2(-e^{i\alpha})+C_1+C_2$$
Following similar steps, we find the antiderivative of $K$:
$$K=\frac{i \left(2 \, \text{Li}_2 \left(e^{i \alpha}\right) + \ln \left(e^{i \alpha} - 1\right)\right) - i e^{-2 i \alpha} \left(\ln \left(1 - e^{i \alpha}\right) - e^{i \alpha}\right) + \alpha}{2}+C_3$$
And finally,
$$I_1=i\left(J-K\right)= \boxed{\text{Li}_2(e^{i \alpha})- \text{Li}_2(-e^{i \alpha}) - \frac{1}{2} e^{-2i \alpha} \ln \left( \frac{1 - e^{i \alpha}}{1 + e^{i \alpha}} \right) - \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{e^{i \alpha} + 1}{e^{i \alpha} - 1} \right) + e^{-i \alpha} + C}$$
And this is the antiderivative in terms of $x$:
$$I_1=\boxed{\operatorname{Li}_2(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}) - \frac{1}{4} \ln\left( \frac{x + 1}{x - 1} \right) \left( 1 - (x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1})^2 \right) + x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + C}$$
Upon evaluating, we obtain the following:
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left( \frac{x+1}{x-1} \right) \left( x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) \, dx &= -i\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{i\alpha}}{1-e^{i\alpha}}\right) \left(1-e^{-2i\alpha}\right) \, d\alpha\\&=\left[\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\color{red}{\frac12\ln\left(\frac{2}{0}\right)}+\color{blue}{\frac12\ln(0)}+1\right]-\left[-\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\color{blue}{\frac12\ln(0)}+\color{red}{\frac12\ln\left(\frac{2}{0}\right)}-1\right]\overset{?}{=}\frac{\pi^2+4}{2}
\end{aligned}$$
According to Wolfram Alpha, the identity is correct, so I assume that somehow WA manages to get rid of the singularities. Indeed, if the singularities cancel out, then my calculations show that the identity is correct. If possible, how can we justify the cancellation of these singularities? I suppose this is where some peculiarities of Complex Analysis come into play, which are beyond my knowledge.
By the way, the other identity can be proven even more easily using exponential substitution.

On $[-1,1]$, $x^2-1$ is negative, thus $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not well defined. for $x\in [0,1]$ $\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}$ is negative thus its logarithm is not well defined too.

$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \left(x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)dx=2$

@FDP: Yes, I am aware of that. But how about if we assume a real domain and a complex range for the integrand? Why does your result not match Wolfram Alpha's? Is WA wrong?

WA gives $6.9348 \approx{ \frac{\pi^2}{2} +2}$

Mathematica knows the antiderivative.

Yes, WA knows the antiderivative  too

Instead of deleting and reposting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4944629/is-this-integral-identity-correct, you should have edited the latter to improve it. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31572/is-it-allowed-to-repost

Let’s consider the hyperbolic function substitution $x=\cosh(i\theta)$.  Then our indefinite integral is transformed into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & = \int \ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right) d x \\&=i \int\ln \left(\frac{\cosh \frac{\theta i}{2}}{\sinh \frac{\theta i}{2}}\right) e^{-\theta i} \sinh (i \theta) d \theta \\
& =i\left[  \underbrace{ \int \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{-i \theta}}{1-e^{-i \theta}}\right) d \theta}_{J} -  \underbrace{ \int e^{-2 \theta i} \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{-\theta i}}{1-e^{-\theta i}}\right)d\theta}_{K} \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}J&=\int \ln \left(1+e^{-i \theta}\right) d \theta-\int \ln \left(1-e^{-i \theta}\right) d \theta\\&= -i \operatorname{Li_2}  \left(-e^{-i \theta}\right)+i \operatorname{Li_2}  \left(e^{-i \theta}\right)+C_1 \end{aligned}
$$

Via integration by parts, we have
$$\begin{aligned} K&= -\frac{1}{2 i} \int \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{-\theta i}}{1-e^{-\theta i}}\right) d\left(e^{-2 \theta i}\right)\\&= -\frac{1}{2i} e^{-2 \theta i} \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{-\theta i}}{1-e^{-\theta i}}\right)-\int \frac{e^{-i \theta}}{e^{2 i \theta}-1} d \theta \\& =-\frac{1}{2 i} e^{-2 \theta i} \ln \left(\frac{1+e^{-\theta i}}{1-e^{-\theta i}}\right)+\int \frac{e^{-i \theta}\left(e^{2 i \theta}-1\right)+e^{i \theta}}{e^{2 i \theta}-1} \\
& =-\frac{1}{2 i} e^{-2 \theta i} \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}+1}{e^{\theta i}-1}\right)+\frac{e^{-i \theta}}{-i}+\frac{1}{2 i} \ln \left(\frac{e^{i \theta}+1}{e^{i \theta}-1}\right)  \\
& =-\frac{1}{2 i} \left(e^{-2 \theta i}-1\right) \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}+1}{e^{\theta i}-1}\right)-\frac{e^{-i \theta}}{i}+C_2\end{aligned}$$
Combining them yields
$$\begin{aligned} I= \operatorname{Li_2}  \left(-e^{-i \theta}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2} \left(e^{-i \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-2 \theta i}-1\right) \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-1}{e^{\theta i}+1}\right)-e^{-i\theta}+C \end{aligned}$$
Plugging back the limits $0$ and $\pi$ into $I$ yields our integral
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{-1}^1 \ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right) d x \\= & {\left[ \operatorname{Li_2}  \left(-e^{-i \theta}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2} \left(e^{-i \theta}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-2 \theta i}-1\right) \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-1}{e^{\theta i}+1}\right)\right.} \left.+e^{-i \theta}\right]_0^\pi \\
= & \operatorname{Li_2} (1)-\operatorname{Li_2} (-1)+\frac{1}{2} \lim _{\theta \rightarrow \pi}\left(e^{-2 \theta i}-1\right) \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-1}{e^{\theta i}+1}\right) +1\\&-\operatorname{Li_2} (-1)+ \operatorname{Li_2} (1)+\frac{1}{2} \lim _{\theta \rightarrow 0}\left(e^{-2 \theta i}-1\right) \ln \left(\frac{e^{\theta i}-1}{e^{\theta i}+1}\right) +1 \\
= & 2\left(\operatorname{Li_2} (1)-\operatorname{Li_2} (-1)+1\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi^2+4}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

Definitely helps. Thank you!

Mathematica splits the integrand into real and imaginary parts as
$$\left(\pi\sqrt{1-x^2} - x \log \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) + i \left(\pi x + \sqrt{1-x^2} \log \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$
The imaginary part vanishes by symmetry.
